# Bluetooth won't work anymore (plug in dongle to use bluetooth)

Tags: 17.10, bluetooth

I have a Razer Blade Stealth. I've been using bluetooth for months without any problems. Today I did a lot of tries to connect to my phone and use its internet through bluetooth. After many connections and disconnections, my bluetooth stopped working. When I go to the bluetooth GUI manager it says "No bluetooth found. Plug in dongle to use bluetooth".

I tried to reboot several times but it won't work.

I use ubuntu 17.10. I don't know which outputs to post so please give me one.

**UPDATE:**

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1535]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
3b:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961 [144d:a804]
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f3:2356 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1532:0220 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:579f Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0cf3:e300 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 22b8:2e24 Motorola PCS 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1050:0406 Yubico.com 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.000000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x52 (or later)
[    0.059864] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    2.223371] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin (v1.1)
[    4.370391] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
[    4.701800] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:01:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    4.701811] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:01:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    4.706130] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00051-QCARMSWP-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp crc32 c3fd4411
[13660.881937] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[13660.881993] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[13660.882297] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[13660.882300] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[13660.882305] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[13660.899738] Bluetooth: hci0: using rampatch file: qca/rampatch_usb_00000302.bin
[13660.899740] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA: patch rome 0x302 build 0x138, firmware rome 0x302 build 0x111
[13660.927637] Bluetooth: hci0: using NVM file: qca/nvm_usb_00000302.bin
[13660.981096] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[13660.981098] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[13660.981100] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[13661.355021] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[13661.355026] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[13661.355030] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: @Jeremy31 it looks like rebooting many times didn't work. However, closing and reopening the notebook lid worked. I'm posting the output anyways

Comment: Actually that version is unsupported now, install 18.04 and see if it is better